# find is not working to check email in db

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying this code to check if there is any account with the same e-mail that is send in a new registration.

Why `var_dump($arr_user_db);` output one result if the value of `$email` is new in the database?

```
public function checkUserDatabase($email=null, $id_fb=null) {
        if(!is_null($email) && is_null($id_fb)){
            unset($arr_user_db);
            $arr_user_db = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('User.email' == $email)));
            var_dump($email); //string 'mersdfsdfda@example.com' (length=28)
            var_dump($arr_user_db);//output an account.

        }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
            $arr_user_db = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('User.email' == $email)));
```

should be:

```
            $arr_user_db = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('User.email' => $email)));
```